# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL multi-master replication?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, replication

Is there an MSSQL equivalent of MySQL's multi-master replication? If so, is it available in SQL Express 2008? I've also seen it referred to as two node circular replication.

Basically, I have an in-office database that I want to be perfectly (relatively :) )in sync with a cloud database (we will have access via VPN). Reads and writes occur at both nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answers. I'm adding this question to my favorites if only for the awesome links.

Because of budget constraints, I am thinking of using MySQL in this case. It will actually be cheaper for us to migrate our current database to MySQL and configure multi-master rather than picking up enterprise licensing and writing our own solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15). Is an Enterprise only feature. Another option is an updatable subscription for Transactional Replication, see [Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx). And finally you can roll your own using [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166071(v=SQL.90).aspx), which is the only option which will work with an Express client, as long as the 'cloud' edition is non-Express.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and Standard editions offer:

- [Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx)
- [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)
- [Log Shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx)

SQL Server 2008 Express has **limited** functionality with:

- [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx)
- [Log Shipping](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Get-SQL-Server-log-shipping-functionality-without-Enterprise-Edition)

In both cases, you'll need to write a customized solution.

There is an excellent chapter in [SQL Server MVP Deep Dives](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/) called "The Poor Man's SQL Server Log Shipping." It will take you through the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

When you say a cloud database, do you mean SQL Azure? If so, SQL Azure doesn’t support replication.

If your cloud database is a full copy of SQL Server (i.e. not Express) you can set up a transactional publication with updatable subscriptions, or use a merge publication. Both options will let you synchronise changes in either database.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, you can use SQL Server Express for replication, but only as a subscriber. The publisher needs to be Workgroup edition or above.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have posted, I'd also mention merge replication, and an article on MSDN about [Selecting the Appropriate Type of Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565(SQL.100).aspx). Basically, whether you choose Merge or Transactional (with updating subscribers) depends on what the proportion of writes are at the different nodes, and the likelihood of conflicting changes.